# How do Run Code When Scrapy Ended or Run Again for Error

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to run `scrapy` again if there is an error file, as I'm scrapping amazon and sometimes it blocks requests so I have to save the corresponding URL to a specified error file using `try/except` doing this all fine, but how can I run scrapy again if there is a file of error? Should I create another script for this?

Error File Looks Like this:

```
URL
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09XRCVVNG
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B097PZT7J3
......
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0881YZJ45
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N6SEXI5
```

Main File:

```
ISBN,PERMALINK,Main Link,Brand,Price
B085K...,Razer-Raptor-..ble,https://www.a...47.FM,Razer,$619.95
B085...,Razer-Rap...e,https://www.am....,Razer,$619.95
B095...,Razer-...e,https://www.amazon.com/..,$797.49
B087...,A....r,https://www.amazon.com/A...,Alienware,
```

I'm a beginner at scrapy and I don't know what to search for. Please help me out with a working solution.

Comment: you could create a new spider that exclusively handles those links, or you could feed them back into the scheduler so it can try them again, although I the chances of it succeeding after already failing once are probably low.  and you would have to turn off scrapy's duplicate request filter.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a list and pop the first element of this list and if this element is an error, then append this element in the same list. You only need to control the number of errors that you allow.

```
import requests as r
import pandas as pd

max_error = 5

print("Start")

df_urls = pd.read_csv('./input/urls.csv')
print("DataFrame")
print(df_urls)

urls = list(df_urls.values)
print("Vector")
print(urls)

error_list = []
error_count = 0
while len(urls) >0 and error_count <= max_error:
    try:
        url = urls.pop(0)[0]
        x = r.get(url)
        print(x.status_code)
    except:
        urls.append(url)
        print("Error url:" + str(url))
        error_count += 1

print("Number of error: " + str(error_count))
print("Finish")
```

Url File

URLs

[How do Run Code When Scrapy Ended or Run Again for Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73003565/how-do-run-code-when-scrapy-ended-or-run-again-for-error)

[How do Run Code When Scrapy Ended or Run Again for Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73003565/how-do-run-code-when-scrapy-ended-or-run-again-for-error)

https://stackoverhflow.com/questions/9399900358/is-there-a-decent-alternative-to-

Output:

```
Start
DataFrame
                                                urls
0  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73003565/h...
1  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73003565/h...
2  https://stackoverhflow.com/questions/939990035...
Vector
[array(['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73003565/how-do-run-code-when-scrapy-ended-or-run-again-for-error'],
      dtype=object), array(['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73003565/how-do-run-code-when-scrapy-ended-or-run-again-for-error'],
      dtype=object), array(['https://stackoverhflow.com/questions/9399900358/is-there-a-decent-alternative-to-dynamic-cast'],
      dtype=object)]
200
200
Error url:https://stackoverhflow.com/questions/9399900358/is-there-a-decent-alternative-to-dynamic-cast
Error url:h
Error url:h
Error url:h
Error url:h
Error url:h
Number of error: 6
Finish

Process finished with exit code 0
```